# How to move ImageView?

Tags: android

There are four ImageVIews with colors above and four below.

And there are buttons connected to each color.

If you press the button, the visibility of the image of the same color is gone.

If orange is gone, and pink, skyblue, and emerald is gone, I would like to have purple next to blue.

Should I use another layout or is there any other way?

I don't know what to do.

It's activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/redImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:tint="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/greenImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:tint="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/blueImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:tint="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/orangeImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:tint="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/purpleImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:tint="@android:color/holo_purple" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pinkImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:tint="#ffccff" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/skyblueImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:tint="#66ffff" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/emeraldImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:tint="#99ff99" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/redButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Red" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/greenButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Green" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/blueButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Blue" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/orangeButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Orange" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout3">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/purpleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Purple" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pinkButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffccff"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Pink" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/skyblueButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#66ffff"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="SkyBlue" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/emeraldButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#99ff99"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Emerald" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It's MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView redImage, greenImage, blueImage, orangeImage, purpleImage, pinkImage, skyblueImage, emeraldImage;
    Button redButton, greenButton, blueButton, orangeButton, purpleButton, pinkButton, skyblueButton, emeraldButton;
    boolean b1 = true, b2 = true, b3 = true, b4 = true, b5 = true, b6 = true, b7 = true, b8 = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        redImage = findViewById(R.id.redImage);
        greenImage = findViewById(R.id.greenImage);
        blueImage = findViewById(R.id.blueImage);
        orangeImage = findViewById(R.id.orangeImage);
        purpleImage = findViewById(R.id.purpleImage);
        pinkImage = findViewById(R.id.pinkImage);
        skyblueImage = findViewById(R.id.skyblueImage);
        emeraldImage = findViewById(R.id.emeraldImage);

        redButton = findViewById(R.id.redButton);
        greenButton = findViewById(R.id.greenButton);
        blueButton = findViewById(R.id.blueButton);
        orangeButton = findViewById(R.id.orangeButton);
        purpleButton = findViewById(R.id.purpleButton);
        pinkButton = findViewById(R.id.pinkButton);
        skyblueButton = findViewById(R.id.skyblueButton);
        emeraldButton = findViewById(R.id.emeraldButton);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.redButton:
            b1 = !b1;

            if(!b1) {
                redImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                redImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            break;

            case R.id.greenButton:
                b2 = !b2;

                if(!b2) {
                    greenImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    greenImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                break;

            case R.id.blueButton:
                b3 = !b3;

                if(!b3) {
                    blueImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    blueImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                break;

            case R.id.orangeButton:
                b4 = !b4;

                if(!b4) {
                    orangeImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    orangeImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                break;

            case R.id.purpleButton:
                b5 = !b5;

                if(!b5) {
                    purpleImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    purpleImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                break;

            case R.id.pinkButton:
                b6 = !b6;

                if(!b6) {
                    pinkImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    pinkImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                break;

            case R.id.skyblueButton:
                b7 = !b7;

                if(!b7) {
                    skyblueImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    skyblueImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                break;

            case R.id.emeraldButton:
                b8 = !b8;

                if(!b8) {
                    emeraldImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    emeraldImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Plz help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use GridView or RecyclerView instead. An other way when you want hide an ImageView you set gone the last ImageView and change color of others